# Does memoir miss clear page before TOC by design? If so, is there a reason? Also, is there an option (other than cleardoublepage) to change behavior?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, books, clearpage

Take this simple example

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{itemize}
   \item ciao
\end{itemize}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{a}
\end{document}
```

(For context, I'm using that `itemize` as a todo list not to forget some things I'll have to do towards the end of the work I'm doing.)

You'll see that the `itemize` environment is at page i, whereas the toc is at page iii. So far so good.

For the purpose of creating end notes via `\pagenote`, I changed the class from `book` to `memoir`.

The unexpected result is that now the toc starts right after the `itemize`.

- Is this by design of the `memoir` class?

  - If so, you know the rational of the design decision?
- What is the proper way to recover `book`s behavior in this respect?

  - I can certainly put a `\cleardoublepage` right before `\tableofcontents`, but I'm not sure that's the way; maybe `memoir` has an option for it?

Comment: see page 150 of the documentation (9.2 THE CLASS TOC METHODS).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I guess your's an answer.